# Retrieve friends' birthdays using Facebook JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Facebook user's friends information using JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324396/how-to-get-facebook-users-friends-information-using-javascript-sdk)

I want to show  my Facebook friends' birthdays using the Facebook API but I don't know how to use it. How can I do that?

First Facebook login, then friend's birthday..

Please don't give me Facebook developer address my English is not good, please give me a example

Comment: Well then you should improve your English and try writing some code. We are not going to write your code but rather help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `friends_birthday` permission and then query:

```
SELECT uid,name,birthday FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

The inner query will get all the friends' ids and the outer will get their ids, names and birthday dates.

Comment: how to give the permission for friends_birthday.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but after reading the [API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) it seems once the user authorizes the app, you will need to ask for their list of friends:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {  // your JavaScript here });
```

You can then pull bithdays of each friend by calling:

```
FB.api('/USER_ID/birthday', function(response) { // Display birthdays here });
```

Remember you need explicit permission from the user for this item.

More info:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/481

Hope that helps!